# ClamAV: suppress all output except summary

Tags: bash, command-line, clamav

When using [Clam AntiVirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamav) from within [GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), how should one invoke `clamscan` such that it will reliably suppress all output **except** the final summary?

These attempts don't work:

- `clamscan --quiet`. Suppresses the final summary.
- `clamscan -o -r ~/ 2>/dev/null`. Prints lines that aren't "OK" (but which don't necessarily indicate an infection: e.g. files that are simply empty files, or symbolic links) to `stdout`. Those lines therefore bypass the redirect and are still printed on the terminal in addition to the final summary.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such switches provided by `clamscan` itself to suppress output, but you can pipe it's output or generated log file to an awk script to filter.

Assuming `-o` is set and `-v` is **not** set.

File: `filter.awk`: (set `chmod +x filter.awk`)

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        split("Symbolic link,Excluded,Empty file", col2, ",")
        FS=": "
}
{
        skip_line = 0
        for (i in col2) {
                if ($2 == col2[i]) {
                        skip_line++
                        break
                }
        }
        # uncomment next 4 lines below to remove FOUND info
        #if (skip_line == 0) {
        #        if ($2 ~ /FOUND/) {
        #                skip_line++
        #        }
        }

        if (skip_line == 0) {
                print $line
        }
}
```

example usage:

```
clamscan -o -r /home | /path/filter.awk
```

or

```
cat /var/log/clamscan.log | /path/filter.awk
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it seems that rather than solely affecting `clamscan`'s output, your suggested solution would also affect `clamscan`'s behaviour. For example, if the user wanted to suppress all `clamscan` output except the summary, while still including directory and file symlinks, then your solution would not work, because it would achieve the former only at the expense of the latter.

Comment: I've updated my answer.. good luck

Answer (score 1):

`--infected` works to only print the summary, unless you have infected files of course

Comment: still prints warnings